# Getting importerror when importing matplotlib.pyplot

Tags: matplotlib, anaconda

So Im getting the following error when I import matplotlib.pyplot:

```
    ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-18-413b0dcce8d2> in <module>()
      1 import pandas as pd
----> 2 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
      3 data=pd.read_csv("fifa_countries_audience.csv")
      4 del data['country']
      5 print(data)

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py in <module>()
     30 from cycler import cycler
     31 import matplotlib
---> 32 import matplotlib.colorbar
     33 from matplotlib import style
     34 from matplotlib import _pylab_helpers, interactive

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\colorbar.py in <module>()
     30 
     31 import matplotlib as mpl
---> 32 import matplotlib.artist as martist
     33 import matplotlib.cbook as cbook
     34 import matplotlib.collections as collections

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\artist.py in <module>()
     14 import matplotlib
     15 from . import cbook, docstring, rcParams
---> 16 from .path import Path
     17 from .transforms import (Bbox, IdentityTransform, Transform, TransformedBbox,
     18                          TransformedPatchPath, TransformedPath)

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\path.py in <module>()
     24 
     25 from . import _path, rcParams
---> 26 from .cbook import (_to_unmasked_float_array, simple_linear_interpolation,
     27                     maxdict)
     28 

ImportError: cannot import name '_to_unmasked_float_array'
```

Anyone has idea what might be the case? I tried reinstalling matplotlib, updating it, updating conda but it didnt solve the case.

Comment: Did you try importing matplotlib as a whole? I mean "import matplotlib" then referencing pyplot. Maybe try "from matplotlib import pyplot" as well. I've never seen an import error so complex before :p

Comment: Looks like i can import matplotlib but then it gives error when i try to import pyplot

Comment: Such errors would suggest you have a problem with your matplotlib install. Reinstalling may help.

Comment: I've sometimes encountered errors when importing pyplot directly. I always fist `import matplotlib` and on the next row `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt`. I have no idea why this works and why importing pyplot alone doesn't, but does this exact sequence of imports work for you?

Comment: @AlexT were you able to resolve this, as I am also facing this issue. Installing and uninstalling doesn't seem to work.

Comment: I think I solved it by reinstalling anaconda